# dblink for AWS RDS mysql or AWS Aurora (MySQL combatible)

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, dblink

I am using AWS RDS MySQL and plan to move to Aurora (MySQL combatible).

I am looking for a method to use dblink between db instances as what Aurora (PostgreSQL combatible) can do.
Any one know how to do this or this is impossible with MySQL?

Thanks in advance.